# WebBrowser Inject Javascript To Set the Focus to the First Input Box

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I would like to inject a javascript in order to set the focus to the first input box.

My current code is this:

```
Me.WebBrowser1.Focus()

Dim i&
Dim JS(100) As String

'The following Javascript-injection ensures, that the first
'found input-element (if there is one) will be focused
' i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "<script>"
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');"
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "for(i=0; i<inputElements.length; i++)"
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "{"
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "  if (inputElements[i].type != 'hidden')"
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "  {"
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "    if (inputElements[i].disabled == false)"
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "    {"
'  If uSetFocusToFirstBox Then
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "      inputElements[i].focus();"
' End If
'If uScrollIntoView Then
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "      inputElements[i].scrollIntoView(true);"
'End If
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "      break;"
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "    }"
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "  }"
i = i + 1 : JS(i) = "}"

Dim head As HtmlElement = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
Dim scriptEl As HtmlElement = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script")
Dim element As IHTMLScriptElement = DirectCast(scriptEl.DomElement, IHTMLScriptElement)
element.text = Join(JS, "")
head.AppendChild(scriptEl)
Me.WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello")
```

Does anybody see my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code is OK in general and works for me, but needs to add `Microsoft.mshtml` reference. Also You may have some other input, like `submit` and it may focus on them. Also you may not have a head element.  Also you can write the code more clean. As an other option you don't need to inject script in the document to focus on an element. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Set Focus on First Text Input**

**Option 1 - Without Script**

You don't need to inject script to the document. You can handle  [`DocumentCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event and there, find input elements using [`GetElementByTagName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx) and find the first input with `type="text"` which is enabled and then call [`Focus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.focus(v=vs.110).aspx), it also automatically scrolls the focused input to the view:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) _
    Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    Dim firstTextBox = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input") _
                         .Cast(Of HtmlElement)() _
                         .Where(Function(element)
                                    Return element.GetAttribute("type") = "text" And _
                                           element.Enabled = True
                                End Function) _
                         .FirstOrDefault()

    If (firstTextBox IsNot Nothing) Then
        firstTextBox.Focus()
    End If 
End Sub
```

**Option 2 - Inject Script**

You don't need to use script for this reason, but just for case that you need to inject script, here is an example. You should add a reference to `Microsoft.mshtml` to the project and write such code:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) _
    Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    Dim scriptText = "var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');" & _
                     "for(i=0; i<inputElements.length; i++){" & _
                     "  if (inputElements[i].type == 'text' && !inputElements[i].disabled){" & _
                     "      inputElements[i].focus();" & _
                     "      inputElements[i].scrollIntoView(true);" & _
                     "      break;" & _
                     "  }" & _
                     "}"

    Dim head As HtmlElement = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
    Dim script As HtmlElement = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script")
    Dim scriptElement As IHTMLScriptElement = DirectCast(script.DomElement, IHTMLScriptElement)
    scriptElement.text = scriptText
    head.AppendChild(script)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! You are really experienced!