# Possible to embed javascript script in webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am trying to load this javascript in a form somehow

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/744_RC08/embed_loader.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("TIMESERIES", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"programming","geo":"","time":"all"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {}); </script>
```

The only way I could think of was to add it to an html document and load that in to a webbrowser control like so:

HTML DOC:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>test</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/744_RC08/embed_loader.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("TIMESERIES", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"dominos pizza","geo":"","time":"all"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {}); </script> 
</BODY>
</html>
```

Code:

```
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\test.html")
```

Seems simple enough but nothing loads at all.
Is this not possible or Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c-sharp+javascript+injection&ie=&oe= will tell you about injecting JavaScript into a WebForm. You can always add your own JavaScript to the HEAD portion of a document - whether it's served by IIS or PHP or whatever. If you want to place it dynamically (once the response has started), then use the injection method.

Comment: Read option 2 of this post: [WebBrowser Inject Javascript To Set the Focus to the First Input Box](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34462373/3110834)

Comment: Or if you know that you have an Html file you can call WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\test.html"), This will start a "navigation" procedure witch will load your js.